# degenerate positions in motifs -bash

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I am new to coding and writing a shell script which searches for motifs in protein sequence files and prints their location if present.
But these motifs have degenerate positions.

For example,
A motif can be (psi, psi,x, psi) where psi=(I, L or V) and x can be any of the 20 amino acids.

I would search a set of sequences for the occurrence of this motif. However, my protein sequences are exact sequences, i.e. they have no ambiguity, like:

```
>
MSGIALSRLAQERKAWRKDHPFGFVAVPTKNPDGTMNLMNWECAIPGKKGTPWEGGL
```

Would like the search for the all possible exact instances of the motif in the protein sequence which is present in fasta file.
I have a rough code which I know is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
x=(A C G H I L M P S T V D E F K N Q R W Y)
psi=(I L V)
alpha=(D E)
motif1=($psi,$psi,$x,$psi)

  for f in *.fasta ; do
    if grep -q "$motif1" <$f ; then   
         echo $f
         grep "^>" $f | tr -d ">"
         grep -v ">" $f | grep -aob "$motif1"
     fi
  done
```

Appreciate any help in finding my way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Could you include a small snippet of example data and indicate which entries contain the patterns you are looking for? See also the guidance for how to include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @tripleee I have minimised the code and elaborated the question. Thank you for the guidance! I am new to this. Can you help me with the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is an excellent tool for orchestrating other tools, but it's not particularly well suited to analyzing the contents of files.

A common arrangement is to use the shell to run Awk over a set of files, and do the detection logic in Awk instead. (Other popular tools are Python and Perl; I would perhaps tackle this in Python if I were to start from scratch.)

Regardless of the language of your script, you should [avoid code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself); refactor to put parameters in variables and then run the code with those parameters, or perhaps move the functionality to a function and then call it with different parameters.  For example,

```
scan () {
    local f
    for f in *.fasta; do
        # Inefficient: refactor to do the grep only once, then decide whether you want to show the output or not
        if grep -q "$1" "$f"; then
            # Always, always use double quotes around file names
            echo "$f"
            grep "^>" "$f" | tr -d ">"
            grep -v ">" "$f" | grep -aob "$1"
        fi
    done
}

case $motif in
    1)     scan "$SIM_Type_1";;   # Notice typo in variable name
    2)     scan "$SIM_Type_2";;   # Ditto
    3)     scan "$SIM_Type_3";;   # Ditto
    4)     scan "$SIM_Type_4";;   # Ditto
    5)     scan "$SIM_TYPE_5";;   # Notice inconsistent variable name
    alpha) scan "$SIM_Type_alpha";;
    beta)  scan "$SIM_Type_beta";;
esac
```

You are declaring the `_*Type_*` variables (or occasionally `*_TYPE_*` -- the shell is case sensitive, and you should probably use the same capitalization for all the variables just to make it easier for yourself) as arrays, but then you are apparently attempting to use them as regular scalars. I can only guess as to what you intend for the variables to actually contain; but I'm guessing you want something like

```
# These are strings which contain regular expressions
x='[ACGHILMPSTVDEFKNQRWY]'
psi='[ILV]'
psi_1='[IV]'
alpha='[DE]'
# These are strings which contain sequences of the above regexes
# The ${variable} braces are not strictly necessary, but IMHO help legibility
SIM_Type_1="${psi}${psi}${x}${psi}"
SIM_Type_2="${psi}${x}${psi}${psi}"
SIM_Type_3="${psi}${psi}${psi}${psi}"
SIM_Type_4="${x}${psi}${x}${psi}"
SIM_TYPE_5="${psi}${alpha}${psi}${alpha}${psi}"
SIM_Type_alpha="${psi_1}${x}${psi_1}${psi}"
SIM_Type_beta="${psi_1}${psi_1}.${x}${psi}"
# You had an empty spot here   ^ I guessed you want to permit any character?
```

If you really wanted these to be arrays, the way to access the contents of the array is `"${array[@]}"` but then that will not produce something we can directly pass to `grep` or Awk so I went with declaring these as strings containing regular expressions for the motifs.

But to reiterate, Awk is probably a better language for this, so let's refactor `scan` to be an Awk script.

```
# This replaces the function definition above
scan () {
    awk -v re="$1" '{ if (/^>/) label=$0
        else if (idx = match($0, re, result) {
            if (! printed) { print FILENAME; printed = 1 }
            print len + idx ":" result[0]
        }
        len += 1+length($0)  # one for the newline
      }
      # Reset printed if we skip to a new file
      FNR == 1 { printed = 0 }' *.fasta
}
```

The main complication here is reimplementing the `grep -b` byte offset calculation.  If that is not strictly necessary (perhaps a line number would suffice?) then the Awk script can be reduced to a somewhat more trivial one.

Your use of `grep -a` suggests that perhaps your input files contain DOS newlines. I think this will work fine regardless of this.

The immediate benefit of this refactoring is that we avoid scanning the potentially large input file twice. We only scan the file once, and print the file name on the first match.

If you want to make the script more versatile, this is probably also a better starting point than the `grep | tr` solution you had before.  But if the script does what you need, and the matches are often near the beginning of the input file, or the input files are not large, perhaps you don't actually want to switch to Awk after all.

Notice also that like your `grep` logic, this will not work if a sequence is split over several lines in the FASTA file and the match happens to straddle one of the line breaks.

Finally, making the script prompt for interactive input is a design wart.  I would suggest you accept the user choice as a command-line argument instead.

```
motif=$1
```

So you'd use this as `./scriptname alpha` to run the `alpha` regex against your FASTA files.

Another possible refactoring would be to read all the motif regexs into a slightly more complex Awk script and print all matches for all of them in a form which then lets you easily pick the ones you actually want to examine in more detail. If you have a lot of data to process, looping over it only once is a huge win.

Comment: I composed the bulk of this before you edited the code in your question, so this references the full script you posted earlier. Several of the criticisms here affect details which are not present in your much simplified minimal script.